# enabling let's encript ssl certificate for two domains

Tags: ssl

I have a server lets say on ip address 111.111.111.111, I have two domains one `.com` and one `.org` and for the `.com` I am setting dns and for `.org` I am redirecting it to `.com`.
I want to get ssl certificate so I used both domain names in the certificate but I face `Certificate name mismatch` error. 
So My question is how I can get a certificate from let's Encrypt service that supports both `org` and `com` domains?
should I set both domain's dns or a simple forwarding works fine?
thanks so much

Comment: I believe you should generate one cert for each domain

Comment: @Guilherme but How should I configure nginx in that case?

Comment: You should generate the cert per domain, not per IP. That way, you will have two separate certs. I never used nginx, but I believe you could use certbot for the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is not directly the certificates but the configuration of Nginx. I advise you not to carry out your reasoning by Ip but by domain.

You have a server and two domains: domain1.com & domain2.org.

So that these two domains can point to the same application, you just need to create two Vhosts in Nginx with the required configuration. (Simple, without Https)

To add the https certificates, you just have to execute the Let's Encrypt procedure on each of your Vhost.

I advise you to go to Certbot if you are not comfortable with Nginx. This script will do the job for you seamlessly.

Is everything clear to you now?

Hope to have helped you a little, good evening;)

Answer (score 1):

If you forget your redirect we are therefore in the presence of two separate domains. Perform the let's encrypt procedure on each domain separately then set up your redirection. Each domain must be in its vhost file.

Looking forward

Comment: @jboleau173 Hi thanks so much for your help, but How can I redirect them to the same app? lets say I have two set of certificates, How can I configure them to point to the same ip in nginx?